# добавить файлы через Input type="file" и сразу отправить через ajax

Tags: javascript, html

Задача стоит в том, что если мы закинули несколько файлов в `input type="file"`, то сразу их же отправить. Сейчас когда закидываю файлы, то нужно ещё нажать кнопку `submit`. Как можно сделать так, чтобы, не нажимая кнопку, сразу отправлять файлы и показать прилойдер пока отправляються файлы?

```
<form action="/profile/uploadFiles" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="js-form-uploadfile">
     <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('briefcaseFileUploader').click()">
         <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         {{ _('Add files') }}
     </button>
     <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" id="briefcaseFileUploader" style="display:none">
     <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">{{ _('Upload files') }}</button>
</form>

js:
$('#briefcaseFileUploader').change(function() {
        $('.js-form-uploadfile').submit();
        $('#ajax-loader').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно событие onchange, куда вешаете нужную функцию.

```
<input type="file" id="input" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

Скорее всего захотите отправлять без перезагрузки, поэтому придется делать через аякс-запрос.